# Execute scrollTop animation on $(window).scroll with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to move the slide once every time that I make scroll in the page. But scroll event doesn't stop and repeat the event. How can I make an animation to move to the next slide color with scrollTop inside `$(window).scroll` just once for every time? See my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7j35882g/1/)

And this is the piece of code which doesn't work :(

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: ($(next).offset().top)
},500);
```

My target is something like that http://www.sincedilla.com/

Comment: It works for me on chrome. You've an error ?

Comment: I need to stop in each slide every time I make scroll, and then if I make again, it has to move to next slide.

Comment: what you exactly want to do with animation.? can you please tell .? are you trying to scroll smoothly or what.?

Comment: @lesrpo if($(next)**.stop()**.prev().length > 0 ){ in your else contion may this will work for you what you want

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara...yes I want a scroll smoothly...like this http://www.sincedilla.com/ :)

Comment: If you don't want to reinvent the wheel I would recommend you to take a look at [fullPage.js](http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) with the `scrollBar:true` option as [in this demo](http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html). 
If you just want it as an exercise, go for it.

Answer (score 1):

this is probably what you need.
The scroll event ve to be prevented until the animation is finished ,
docs for animation http://api.jquery.com/animate/ read the callback section

```
$(this).bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
    if (!animating) {
        animating = true;
        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
            next = $(first).next();
            first = $(next);
            // scroll down
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: ($(next).offset().top)
            }, 900, function(){
                animating = false;
            });
        } else {
            first = $(next).prev();
            next = $(first);
            // scroll up
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: ($(first).offset().top)
            }, 900,function(){
                animating = false;
            });
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fdbh0no8/

Comment: Very good...I just add some new things..http://jsfiddle.net/fdbh0no8/21/...Thanks for your solution @Vanojx...I wanted to put solved but I dont have enough reputation. :)